# Reduction of a union of dictionary values produces unexpected results

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, lambda, functools

I would like to make a union of all dictionary values, which in this case are sets. I only get the expected result if there are exactly two dictionaries in the input list.

**Two dictionaries** in the input list produces the expected result:

```
>>> reduce((lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']), [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}])
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

**Three dictionaries** in the input list produces a TypeError.

Expected result: `set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])`

```
>>> reduce((lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']), [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    reduce((lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']), [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}])
  File "<input>", line 1, in <lambda>
    reduce((lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']), [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}])
TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

**One dictionary** in the input list produces a dictionary instead of a set.

Expected result: `set([1, 2])`

```
>>> reduce((lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']), [{'a': {1, 2}}])
{'a': set([1, 2])}
```

**An empty input list** also produces a different TypeError.

Expected result: `set([])`

```
>>> reduce((lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']), [])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    reduce((lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']), [])
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
```

I need help with understanding what I'm doing wrong and why these results are produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR:

The `reduce(function, iterable)` call recursively applies `function` to elements of the `iterable` *and* the previous results. That means the return type of `function` must be a valid input type!

- In your case, `function` expects `dict`s but produces a `set`. Since it is not possible to call `x['y']` on a `set`, a `TypeError` is raised.
- When `iterable` has only two elements, `function` is applied only *once* and only to these elements. The problem of the return type of `function` not being a valid input type is thus never encountered.

You must first `map` from `dict` to `set`, *then* `reduce` the `set`s.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, map(lambda x: x['a'], [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}]))
#    merge via reduce ^     convert via map ^
```

---

### Why `reduce` fails in some cases

Calling `reduce(function, iterable)` performs the equivalent of this code:

```
def reduce(function, iterable, start=None):
    result = next(iterable) if start is None else start # 1.
    for element in iterable:
        result = function(result, element)              # 2.
    return result
```

This leads to several cases:

1. `iterable` has **one element** and `start` is not set

   - `result` is the first element of `iterable` (`1.`)

     - `function` is never called; its return and input types are inconsequential
2. `iterable` has **two elements** and `start` is not set

   - `result` is the *first element* of `iterable`(`1.`)
   - `function` is called on the *first element* and `next` element(`2.`)

     - `function` never receives its own result; its return type is meaningless
3. `iterable` has **more than two elements** and `start` is not set

   - `result` is the *first element* of `iterable` (`1.`)
   - `function` is called on the *first element* and `next` element (`2.`)
   - `function` is called on the *previous result* and `next` element (`2.`)

     - `function` receives its own result; its return type and input type must match
4. `iterable` is **empty or not empty** and `start` is set

   - same as above if `start` were the first element of `iterable`
5. `iterable` is **empty** and `start` is not set

   - `result` cannot be set and a `TypeError` is raised (`1.`)

In your case, that is:

- **Two dictionaries** is 2. and works as expected.
- **Three dictionaries** is 3. and chokes on the incompatible input and return type.
- **An empty input list** is 5. and fails on the missing input - as expected.

---

### How to do it instead

#### map/reduce

Your `reduce` is actually doing two things at once: it converts/extracts *each* element individually, then merges both the results. That is a classical map/reduce task: one for each element, one for all elements.

You can directly split this up into two separate operations with the `map` and `reduce` builtins:

```
sets = map(lambda x: x['a'], [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}])
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, sets)
```

Of course, you can also nest the two expressions directly.

### comprehension/reduce

The `map` portion can be expressed using a comprehension.

```
sets = (x['a'] for x in [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}])
result = reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, sets)
```

### comprehension/assignment

In Python3.8, you can use an assignment expression in place of the `reduce` as well.

```
result = set()
result = [(result := (result | x['a'])) for x in [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}]]
```

### Use a for loop

Just, you know, write it out.

```
result = set()
for element in [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}]:
    result |= element['a']
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the function passed to `reduce` must be of the same type as the items in the iterator, so that it can keep aggregating the item values with the same function.

In your case, the output of `lambda x, y: x['a'] | y['a']` is a set `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, so when `reduce` tries to aggregate the third item `{'a': {5, 6}}` with `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, it fails because the lambda function treats both `x` and `y` as dicts and tries to get items of each by key `'a'`, which a set does not have.

As for the `TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value` exception, you just need to provide `reduce` with an initial value as the third argument, which in your case should be an empty set `{}`, but you just need to first drop the idea of passing to it a list of dicts and instead pass to it a list of sets.

Answer (score 1):

`reduce` works iteratively, it will apply a reducing aggregation across items of a sequence. For example, given elements `i`, `j` and `k`, together with function `foo`, it will process `foo(foo(i, j), k)`.

In your example, `foo(i, j)` works fine, giving a `set`, but the outer call fails because the result, being a `set`, does not have the key `'a'`. The syntax `[]` in the background calls `__getitem__`, which is why you see an error relating to this method.

**What can you do about it?**

A trivial hack is to have your function output a dictionary, and then access it's only value directly. This ensures that your function always outputs a dictionary with key `'a'`.

```
reduce((lambda x, y: {'a': x['a'] | y['a']}),
       [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}])['a']

# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

More readable, you can define a named function:

```
def foo(x, y):
    return {'a': x['a'] | y['a']}

L = [{'a': {1, 2}}, {'a': {3, 4}}, {'a': {5, 6}}]

reduce(foo, L)['a']
```

Comment: Interesting alternative to the answer by @MisterMiyagi